# How to specify rpc queue size when use wait_for_ready

Tags: grpc, grpc-python

How to specify rpc queue size when use wait_for_ready in grpc-python

Answer (score 0):

gRPC Python doesn't really have a buffer queue layer. Only gRPC Java has similar concept. The wait-for-ready applies to individual RPC but doesn't restrict other RPCs' behavior.